# void replaceLetters(char *text, char original, char new_char) should change text

Tags: c, replace, char, c-strings, function-definition

I've been tryring to solve this problem for hours now.

```
void replaceLetters(char *text, char original, char new_char) 
{
  text = "Randoi";
  for(int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++){
  if(text[i] == original){
  text[i] = new_char;
  }
}
```

if I print out text in this function it's correct, but in the other function where this function is called the text doesn't change and i know there's something wrong with my pointers.

Please give me a hint. Tanks a lot.

Comment: `text = "Randoi";` - why do you have that in there?

Comment: You have overwritten the pointer passed with a new value, pointing to a string literal. You are not allowed to change a string literal. Remove the offending line, and also change the loop condition from `i != '\0';` to `text[i] != '\0';`

Comment: @Mat forget to delete it :D

Comment: Then just change the loop condition. (and add the missing `}` brace.)

Comment: The only reason `text = "Randoi";` is accidentally correct is due to the fact that `"Randoi"` is a *String Literal* and what you are assigning is an *Address* that survives the function return, you do not assign strings in that manner absent a string-literal. Further, since `text` holds the address of a string-literal `text` is immutable -- attempting to modify it will result in a SegFault (most likely)

Comment: You don't need `char *replacedletter = text;`. Just work with `text` and make the one change to the loop condition.

Comment: @WeatherVane 
for(int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(text[i] == text){
    text[i] = new_char;
    }
  }

Comment: No, you have changed sometning else too. Start with the code in the question and make **one change** to the loop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition does not make a sense at least because you overwrote the first parameter

```
text = "Randoi";
```

with the address of a string literal and the condition in the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++){
```

is incorrect. That is the for loop never will make iterations.

You should not use the type `int` for the index and the function should return the result string.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * replaceLetters(char *text, char original, char new_char) 
{
    for ( char *p = text; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p == original ) *p = new_char;
    }

    return text;
}
```

Pay attention to that you may not use the function to change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative progran.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * replaceLetters(char *text, char original, char new_char) 
{
    for ( char *p = text; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p == original ) *p = new_char;
    }

    return text;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "character";
    
    puts( s );
    puts( replaceLetters( s, 'a', 'A' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
character
chArActer
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void replaceLetters(char *text, char original, char new_char) 
{
  for(int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
      if(text[i] == original)
      {
        text[i] = new_char;
      }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char text[] = "Randoi";
    replaceLetters(text,'n','T');
    printf(text);

    return 0;
}
```

The condition of for loop is "for(int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)"

Comment: Still doens't work ... 
If the input is "VW" the Output is "V" and i don't know why?

Comment: could you show your original text and the target?

Comment: I run with `int main()
{
    char text[] = "VWVW";
    replaceLetters(text,'V','T');
    printf(text);

    return 0;
}`
The results is TWTW.

Comment: I run it, and the result is "TWTW". You can check with c++ compiler here (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)